# Select the first new value in a column

Tags: r, unique

I have a data set of 351080 observations that (transposed) looks like this:

```
Subject     1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3  
nationality G G G D D S S S S
```

with:

```
table(dat$Nationality)
```

R simply returns the total number of observations. How can I tell R only to select each subject's nationality once?

Comment: Pssst! There is the http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ site dedicated for data science. Maybe you might get a better help there... About table column formatting, people usually use code blocks (in post editor use the `{}` button, or CTRL + K over selected text).

Comment: clarify what you  mean by "select each subject's nationality once". what does the output you want look like?

Comment: Thanks. I will keep it in mind for next time :).
The data used to look like this after 
table(dat$nationality)
(I'll just use the "data" above for the illustration)

G 3  
D 2
S 4

But I want it to be:  
G 1  

D 2  

S 3  

since there is only one G person, one D person, one S person

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct data:

```
dat <- data.frame(Subject = rep(1:3, each=3),
                  Nationality = rep(c("G","D","S"), each=3))
```

Try this:

```
with(dat,table(tapply(as.character(Nationality),
                      list(Subject),head,n=1)))
## D G S 
## 1 1 1
```

- `with()` looks within the context of the data frame, to avoid typing `dat$` all the time
- `tapply()` runs the specified function (`head`) on each element of the vector (`Nationality`) separated by groups (`list(Subject)`), with optional parameters (`n=1` takes only the first element).
- `as.character()` is ugly but prevents R from converting the factor to numeric codes.
- `table` computes the table.

You could also try this:

```
library("dplyr")
d2 <- dat %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
              summarise(Nationality=head(Nationality,1))
table(d2$Nationality)
```

Test speed:

```
n <- 351078 ## divisible by 3, for convenience
set.seed(101)
nat <- sample(c("G","D","S"),size=n/3,replace=TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(Subject = rep(1:(n/3),each=3),
                  Nationality = rep(nat,each=3))
system.time(tab <- with(dat,table(tapply(as.character(Nationality),
                      list(Subject),head,n=1))))
```

This takes about 1.9 seconds on my machine ...

On the other hand

```
 system.time(tab2 <- with(dat,table(Nationality[!duplicated(Subject)])))
```

takes about 0.02 (!) seconds ...

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast, thank you very much!
Just tried:
'with(dat,table(tapply(as.character(Nationality),
                      list(Subject),head,n=1)))'
And it works!
Thank you very much!